# Colleague is very nice, smart and helpful but stinks. Told him twice but not getting the message

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, cleanliness

I joined work about a month ago. My colleague/mentor smells because I don't think he ever showers. He sits next to me and he's the typical nerdy guy. Sometimes the smell is so bad it makes me sick. I told him about it twice. The first time I said something smells around his area and he said he couldn't smell anything but will check his things later. The next time I straight up told him he smells. He thanked me for telling him and said he will shower (my work places has like 5 showers) but a week later and he smelled everyday.

He's very nice and super helpful so I don't want to make a stand. I also don't want to say anything to the manager because he will know it was me and might matters worse than if I had told him again, plus there is no guarantee that the manager than solve the problem permanently. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Tell him again. Tell him as many times as necessary. Since you volunteered to tell him the first time around, there is no harm in telling him again and again. Does anyone sit next to him? Maybe you could take turns.

Comment: Keep telling him. Sounds like he was grateful the first time you told him.